# Datatables Mixed multiple search in multiple columns with select

Tags: javascript, datatables, multiple-select

I'm making a web page with datatables like this one in the image.
in the top bar (not in the image) i've got a select which must select the record based on the data from three columns.

the "type" column is for the type of record (0 for customers, 1 for suppliers, 2 for orthers)
the "blocked" column lists if the person is blocked (0) or active (1)
the "market" column lists if the person must be in the "market"

the select that i'm using for filtering is like this

```
<select multiple>
        <option value="">All</option>
    <optgroup label="Customers">
        <option value=""> Customers - Active</option>
        <option value=""> Customers - Blocked</option>
        <option value=""> Customers - Market</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Suppliers">
        <option value=""> Suppliers - Active</option>
        <option value=""> Suppliers - Blocked</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Operatore">
        <option value=""> Other - Active</option>
        <option value=""> Other - Blocked</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

What i want to do is perform a multiple selection on the select and pass the data to the search engine of datatables.

so if i clic on "customers - active" it must search in columns type (0), blocked (0), and market (0)
for "suppliers - active" is type (1), blocked (0), and market(0)
for "customers - market" is type(1), blocked(0), and market(1) and so on...

Thank You

Actually is working well with single selection, switching the value of each option, 
,[image: example]

Comment: I think some additional information would be helpful - what is your database? What is your server side language? Are you using an ORM? Basically, you are a looking at dynamically providing a WHERE clause to your query but the practical implementation depends on your tech stack.

Comment: i got a MySql db and all the data are client side handled. it's written in pure php. if i can be more specific please let me know..

Comment: you can have PHP write SQL string based on the filtering - but when doing stuff like that you are exposing yourself to SQL Injection. Consider using an ORM like http://propelorm.org/ to make it a little more secure.